# Understanding transform

Tags: r, plyr

I'm getting a warning message on a basic use of the transform function.  I'm trying to apply a simple custom function to a data frame to create a new variable:

```
change <- function(x) {
   if (x==1) {
    y <- "Code A"
  } else if (x==2) {
    y <- "Code B"
  } else {
    y <- "none"
  }
  return(y)
}
```

I then apply it using:

```
df_test2 <- transform(df, strX=change(x))
```

This gives me the warning below and the results are incorrect (it creates a factor and everything is coded as "none"

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (x == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (x == 2) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `if` is not vectorized, and only uses the first element of a vector.  Perhaps you want `ifelse` instead.

Comment: `transform(..)` uses `base:::transform`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sapply` works, I think. But it might be overkill.

Here goes:

```
df <- data.frame(A=seq(1:5), 
          B=c('green', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'green'),
          C=rnorm(seq(1:5)))
```

Dataframe

```
> df
  A     B          C
1 1 green -1.6728109
2 2   red  1.2073857
3 3  blue -0.8837428
4 4  blue  1.4519152
5 5 green -0.8218307
```

Function

```
change <- function(txt) {
    if (txt=='red') {
        res <- 'Code Red'
    }
    else if (txt=='blue') {
        res <- 'Code Blue'
    }
    else {
        res <- 'none'
    }
    return(res)
}
```

Usage on single string

```
> change('green')
[1] "none"
```

Usage on the `B` vector.

```
> df$changed.B <- sapply(df$B, change)
> df
  A     B          C changed.B
1 1 green -1.6728109      none
2 2   red  1.2073857  Code Red
3 3  blue -0.8837428 Code Blue
4 4  blue  1.4519152 Code Blue
5 5 green -0.8218307      none
```

Answer (score 3):

The results are incorrect because the function `change` is not vectorized, and returns a single element.  This will reflect the first vector entry in `x` and none of the rest.  The single value returned will be assigned to the column in the usual way -- replicate the single returned value to fit the column.  Vectorizing the function is what you need to get the expected results.

To vectorize this function, you can use `ifelse` rather than `if`:

```
change2 <- function(x) ifelse(x==1, "Code A", ifelse(x==2, "Code B", "none"))
```

For the case where vectorizing the function isn't so easy, there is the `Vectorize` function wrapper, to create a vectorized function out of one that accepts only arguments of length 1.  But `ifelse` will perform much better than `Vectorize(change)` using your original definition of `change`.

Using your original definition with a vector as an input shows this error:

```
change(1:3)
[1] "Code A"
Warning message:
In if (x == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Use of `Vectorize` to handle this situation:

```
Vectorize(change)(1:3)
[1] "Code A" "Code B" "none"
```

This returns the same as `change2` defined above:

```
change2(1:3)
[1] "Code A" "Code B" "none"
```

And a quick speed comparison shows that the `ifelse` solution is indeed faster:

```
benchmark(Vectorize(change)(rep(1:3, 1000)), change2(rep(1:3, 1000)), replications=1000,columns=c('test', 'relative'))
                           test relative
2           change2(rep(1:3, 1000))    1.000
1 Vectorize(change)(rep(1:3, 1000))    3.159
```

Comment: +1 because this actually got me on the right track, but doesn't actually answer the question.  I was trying to do this using the transform function. Using change2 still does not properly create a new variable as I'd hoped.  However, your answer suggested to me a different strategy of using apply.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew's response suggested another solution to me that worked for my problem.  I changed my function to:

```
change <- function(df) {
  if (df["x"]==1) {
    y <- "Code A"
  } else if (df["x"]==2) {
    y <- "Code B"
  } else {
    y <- "none"
  }
  return(y)
}
```

And replaced transform with apply:

```
df$f <-apply(df, 1,change)
```

This gives me the result I wanted.